# I need a Java decompiler

Tags: user-interface, class, java, decompiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

Can I have some recommendations on a good GUI based Java decompiler like jd-gui? I need the compiler to be able to save all source code (like a package) at once. The jd-gui can do such a task, just when it saves all the classes are blank. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).

Answer (score 0):

May be [DJ java decompiler](http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Recursive Java Decompiler based on JAD a while ago. See if it will help you.

[Recursive Java Decompiler](http://www.adarshr.com/papers/recursive/)