# jar to .java conversion

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

Can anyone tell me how i can convert jar file to it's corresponding .java source file?

I have jar file from unknown source. Is it possible to get the corresponding .java source file out of jar?

Comment: you can contact its author. otherwise, you're looking for a [decompiler](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+decompiler)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: note that this is likely to be a violation of licenses.

Comment: right answer @JigarJoshi

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can decompile any jar file, by using ,for example, JAD
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29

But if the jar was obfuscated the result may not be very pretty. ;)

Answer (score 0):

My fav decompiler is cavaj, you can download from the following url

http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Normally are in a "jar" archive only the compiled Java files (". class"). But you could theoretically try to decompile these files.

[Here](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) you'll find e.g. a decompiler