# How do I decompile a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, reverse-engineering, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)
>   [How to decompile a whole Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file)

I have a .jar file. Its a single file, but I want to "decompile" it to get at the original java code (or at whatever would be closest to the Java code - something I could understand, and edit). I believe my file is (specifically) a java applet, but its saved as an executable jar file (.jar).

How would I do such a thing?

Comment: One more: [Is JAD the best decompiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler)

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/).

It allows you to decompile jar files with the JD-GUI and browse the class files as source.

Here is another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files/272595#272595).

Comment: It even has an eclipse plugin and works seamlessly while opening class files where source code is not available.

Comment: You can even use Java Decompiler to save the sources of the jar file in an archive which you can later unarchive and see.