# Java decompiler that works with Java 5 (handles enums among other new things)

Tags: java, enums, decompiling

I know this question was asked gzillions of times already, but I am specifically after a decompiler that would handle enums corrently (because the jar I am decompiling uses enums heavily). I tested that both JAD and JD-GUI don't.

Could someone recommend a decompiler (ideally that works under Linux and can easily handle the whole jar without requiring me to write shell scrips)?

EDIT:
Specifically I have issues with constructs like:

```
switch(myEnum) {
case A: ...
case B: ...
}
```

they get decompiled (for both JAD and JD-GUI) as something like:

```
switch ($SWITCH_TABLE$com$MyType()[myEnum.ordinal()]) {
case 1:
case 2:
}
```

where `$SWITCH_TABLE$com$MyType()` is either not declared at all or doesn't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

Comment: According to the question I linked to above http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ provides the best one for Java 5. If this doesn't work for you, then tell us *how* it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't know about JD-GUI but we are using JD-Eclipse which uses an older version of JD-Core that JD-GUI does, and it handles enums as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, java.decompiler.free.fr is JD-GUI, and it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Java 5 **[isn't exactly 'new' anymore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29)** by any stretch of imagination

Comment: @Grzenio: please define "didn't work". Can you define a sample of how it doesn't work? This question is no better than any of the other hunderets of duplicates out there, *unless* you can tell us **what** doesn't work for you.

Comment: @sehe, I can't agree more with you

Comment: I've used JD-GUI before and had mixed results, particularly with obfuscated code -- obfuscation can rename variables to illegal names (such as a.1, a.2, etc.) and JD-GUI passes this through unfixed. JD-GUI can also produce output which uses locals before they are declared. Both of these are easily fixed of course, but for a large project, it leaves a lot of manual work after the decompilation.

Comment: @Grzenio: ah, now I see. Yes, it seems that switches on enums are not completely decompiled with JD-GUI yet, even in unobfuscated code.

Comment: According to [this bug entry](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=node/335) this should have been fixed but I (and it seems others as well) can still reproduce the problem with the current JD-GUI.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, this bug is closed and 2 years old :( I doubt they are actively working on it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to decompile a enum-switch properly. The java-classfile doesn't know about the enum-Typ after compilation, thus your decompiler cant decompile it as you like it.

Enums-Types are all a subtype of `java.lang.Enum`, every enum constant got an ordinal-number which is used in a switch statement. The compiler do a switch on that int-value, a switch over an enum type is simply said syntactic-sugar. If you try to switch on an `null`-enum you will get a NPE.

Comment: Depends how smart the decompiler is I guess. If it is able to find the declaration of the enum, then it should be able to map the ordinal numbers back to names.

Comment: If I decompile the $1 version a class file which switches on an ENUM, I get a list of all the ordinals along with the ENUM constants. It will be possible to decompile this - it just needs coding. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that JD-Java Decompiler is open source :-( and JAD is too old to get up to speed on everything else without major effort.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the product of a research project, [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/), handles Enums particularly well.

As at this time JD-GUI and JAD perform no better than when the OP's question was posted, while CFR version 0.43 produces correct, compilable source, even when fed obfuscated classes.