# How do I convert a java class into a java file?

Tags: java, decompiling

Is there any software to convert a java class into a java file?  I know decomplier is there but I was looking for software to convert a java class into a java file.

Comment: A decompiler *is* software to convert compiled Java (class files) into source files. What do you want which is different?

Comment: Use JAD - [link](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). It is pretty good.

Comment: Do you want to get the source file of an instance of`java.lang.Class`  ?

Answer (score 1):

A decompiler is a software that converts class files into java files :) See the following questions:

[How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

[Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use - http://www.showmycode.com/
It is a free online decoder / decompiler.