# How to extract code from .exe or retrieve lost code in project?

Tags: java, project, exe

I had an entire code in a class Graph2 of my java project. I was trying to use JSmooth to create a .exe file for my program. Then I switched to Launch4j and used it to create the .exe. When I came back to my project, all my source code was gone and this is what it got replaced with:

```
   < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

   < jsmoothproject>

   < arguments></arguments>

   < embeddedJar>false</embeddedJar>

   < initialMemoryHeap>-1</initialMemoryHeap>

   < mainClassName></mainClassName>

   < maximumMemoryHeap>-1</maximumMemoryHeap>

   < maximumVersion></maximumVersion>

   < minimumVersion></minimumVersion>

   < skeletonName><![CDATA[

   < none>]]>

   < /skeletonName>

   < /jsmoothproject>
```

Help?

Comment: its not possible to get source code from exe, try to read it back from your hard disk by some softwares

Comment: ... and add the following to your "TO DO - URGENT" list: 1) set up regular backups for your hard drives, and 2) start using version control ... and/or checking in your source code more often.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSmooth, but do you have any class files corresponding to the lost code -- in that case a decompiler would at least give you something.

Comment: The best would be to use some utility to get back your files... depend on your filesystem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you have at least the class files, decompile them. [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

2) If you don't, you still have the jar file inside the exe generated by JSmooth (or Launch4j).  [JSmooth extracts the jar in the default temporary directory](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N1034F), so make a copy of it while your program is running. From the jar file you can get the class files (with an unzip program), then go to point 1)