# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Tags: java, url, protocols

Why I am getting no protocol if i have http in the url path?

Log:

```
network: Connecting http://xxx.ccc.local/upload/up.php?aa=0&bb=Ap%F3lice+de+Seguro&cc=1028&from=documentos with cookie "CLinkLanguage=en; __utma=232844939.1396040569.1356709687.1357294077.1357902500.12; __utmz=232844939.1356709687.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=232844939.24.10.1357902500; symfony=e0lpbkrcu0bidkpiujd1if4pt4; __utmc=232844939; CLinkLanguage=en; PHPSESSID=uv31kr1vpojvqgnc9ae9nda921"
```

Exception:

```
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

**html**

```
 <APPLET  CODE = "wjhk.jupload.JUploadApplet" ARCHIVE = "upload/wjhk.jupload.jar" WIDTH = "600" HEIGHT = "400" MAYSCRIPT></XMP>
        <PARAM NAME = CODE VALUE = "wjhk.jupload.JUploadApplet" >
        <PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "upload/wjhk.jupload.jar" >
        <PARAM NAME = "type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4">
        <PARAM NAME = "scriptable" VALUE="false">
        <PARAM NAME = "postURL" VALUE ="{$url}">
        <PARAM NAME = "anexosID" VALUE ="{$anexosID}">
        <PARAM NAME = "subanexosID" VALUE ="{$IdConsulta}">
        <PARAM NAME = "companyID" VALUE ="{$companyID}">
        <PARAM NAME = "resultURL" VALUE ="{$resultUrl}">
        <param name="debug" value="true">


    Java 1.4 or higher plugin required.
```

```
<APPLET  CODE = "wjhk.jupload.JUploadApplet" ARCHIVE = "upload/wjhk.jupload.jar" WIDTH = "600" HEIGHT = "400" MAYSCRIPT></XMP>
    <PARAM NAME = CODE VALUE = "wjhk.jupload.JUploadApplet" >
    <PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "upload/wjhk.jupload.jar" >
    <PARAM NAME = "type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4">
    <PARAM NAME = "scriptable" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM NAME = "postURL" VALUE ="http://xxx.ccc.local/upload/up.php?aa=0&bb=Alvar%E1%2Ffg&cc=1028&from=documentos">
    <PARAM NAME = "anexosID" VALUE ="">
    <PARAM NAME = "subanexosID" VALUE ="">
    <PARAM NAME = "companyID" VALUE ="">
    <PARAM NAME = "resultURL" VALUE ="">
    <param name="debug" value="true">


Java 1.4 or higher plugin required.
</APPLET>
```

Comment: Show us the code and show us the *exact* value that you pass in to the `URL` constructor.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, question updated.

Comment: @Esailija, this is an applet, i don't have access to the source code.

Comment: @loops how are you giving this to the applet, show the html or javascript source code. The url passed to the URL constructor is an empty string.

Comment: Are you getting this error..... java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: {$VARS['HOST']}/upload/up.php?aa=0&bb=$idConsulta&cc=$COMPANYID&from=$from
...........

Comment: @Jayamohan no that was his php code that is unrelated

Comment: @loops please just show the resulting html source code, not PHP. You can view it from view-source: in a browser.

Comment: @loops well as you can see, most of the values are empty in the resulting html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the postURL parameter is a URL that can be parsed without exceptions, therefore the problem is somewhere else. What you can do:

- Experiment with various applet parameters
- Ask for support from the developers of the applet
- If you don't have the source code of the applet, you can probably still decompile it, and find out how it works: [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)

The following program shows only that the postURL value is OK for Java:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String s = "http://xxx.ccc.local/upload/up.php?aa=0&bb=Alvar%E1%2Ffg&cc=1028&from=documentos";

        URL url = new URL(s);
        String protocol = url.getProtocol();
        System.out.println(String.format("A::main: protocol = '%s'", protocol));
    }
}
```