# Jenkins | java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Tags: jenkins, url

I have been facing this issue with different Jenkins pipelines :
**java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol**

[image: java_net_MalformedURLException]

I have investigated similar topics in StackOverflow, but none of them seems to be a similar situation :
[java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278320/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol)

My Pipeline :

pipeline {

```
agent {

    docker {

        label 'generic-slave'

        image '$PYTHON_IMAGE'

    }

}

parameters {

    string(name: 'PYTHON_IMAGE', defaultValue: 'tools/python/python3.9.16:2.5', description: 'Image version ')

    string defaultValue: "23.007.000", description: "Version of the application", name: "RELEASE_ID", trim: true

    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'develop', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'

}

options {

    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))

    disableConcurrentBuilds()

    skipStagesAfterUnstable()

}

 stages {
    
    stage('Build') {
         steps {
            sh 'python --version'
         }
        }
  
}
```

}

Do you believe this could be a malconfiguration of my slave's IP, that perhaps can not access the internal repositories in my company ?

Thank you a lot for your help. Any tip on this issue is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved. The issue was in the configurations, under "**Declarative Pipeline (Docker)**", I had to delete the **Docker registry URL** :

[image: Docker registry URL]